# the @ printed as a dot

Tags: c++, string, while-loop

[why the @ printed (.)??][1]

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;

     int main()
    {
    
    string email;
    cin >> email;
    int size = email.size() - 1;
    int i = 0;
    int endsiz = size - 4;

    char dot = '.';
    char at = '@';
    while (((email[i] >= 'a' && email[i] <= 'z') || (email[i] >= 'A' && email[i] <= 'Z') || (email[i] 
    = dot)) && (i <= endsiz) && email[i]!=at)
    {
        cout << email[i] << endl;
        i++;

    }
        
    }
```

I want to the while-loop stop when the ( i ) reaches the @ but as you see the @ printed as a (. ) I don't know why ??
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiGCT.png

Comment: `email[i] = dot` should be `email[i] == dot`

Answer (score 2):

Kindly check your if condition
It should be

```
email[i] == dot
```

In your case,

When you put `email[i] = dot` it basically assigns/replaces char at email[i] with a '.'